# Confused about an inequality on the spectral radius of matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality

Let $\rho(\cdot)$ be the spectral radius operator (NOT the spectral norm). I'm aware that $\rho(AB)\leq\rho(A)\rho(B)$ holds if matrices $A$ and $B$ commute. But what is wrong with the following series of inequalities: let $z$ be an arbitrary vector then 
$||ABz||\leq \rho(A)||Bz||\leq \rho(A)\rho(B)||z||$, thus maximum absolute eigenvalue of $AB$ (i.e. $\rho(AB)$) must be less than $\rho(A)\rho(B)$.

Please help me with this confusion,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply not true in general that

$ \| Ax \|_{2} \leq \rho(A) \| x \|_{2}$.

For example, consider

$A=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 2 \\
1/2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$, so $\rho(A)=1$.  However, if we let

$x=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

then

$Ax=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
2 \\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

and

$\| Ax \|_{2}=2$

but $\rho(A)\| x \|_{2}=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see. The spectral radius can only bound the matrix vector multiplication asymptotically, i.e. $\rho(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}||A^n||^{1/n}$